# How to make scroll end like pull to refresh in scrollview react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, lazy-loading, react-native-flatlist

I want to make a function "Swipe to see detail" like Tiktok app ([Link Example](https://giphy.com/gifs/RINCbohMfbntC1HvoI))
How did we do that?
It didn't like latest item and use "onMomentumScrollEnd"
User have to swipe hard to dispatch this function. If I use onMomentumScrollEnd, it just dispatch when the list at the end

Comment: Are using a Flat-list or what?